# SIM800L http"S" connection problems

Tags: api, ssl, https, tcp, sim800

I have a SIM800L module. Which has R14.18 firmware(supports TLS 1.0 and SSL) in it. I am having trouble to connect to http"S" servers. I can connect http servers no problem there. All this information and steps i got from datasheets, forums and YouTube videos. But i havent seen anyone connect to http"S" servers specifically.
I have no idea what I am missing if someone could rightdown the steps as a dummies guide that would be great.
Thanks in advance.

P.S: I am planing to use this with arduino iot cloud api any help would be appreciated there!

So far i tried;

1. Configuring the bearer and http with AT commands always getting 601,603,605 etc.

- I checked the DNS and SSL cert but I'm not confident there since these are new to me

2. Tried to connect with TCP/IP wasn't able to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out i just needed to be a bit more careful that was all :)